# Is it possible to make a laser by sending sunlight through an optical apparatus?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, energy-conservation, laser, photon-emission

1) Is it possible to create a laser from focused sun light by separating and using only one wavelength of light as a laser and using the proper mechanism to polarize it and make it coherent?

2) If so, would it be possible to use some type of a wavelength filter enabling it to focus different wavelengths for different applications?

Comment: Since photons from the sun are not coherent, there is no mechanism to turn some slice of the spectrum into a laser. At the worst, use a solar panel to power a laser, although you might think that is cheating... Splitting the spectrum requires only a prism.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why some components of sunlight couldn't be used to *pump* a laser (i.e., to achieve a population inversion).

Comment: You may be interested in "How many principles does it take to change a light
bulb . . . into a laser?": https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.04805.pdf

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking about the possibility of making coherent light by filtering incoherent, broad-spectrum sunlight, the answer is "no".  You could filter the light down to a very narrow wavelength band by throwing away all the other wavelengths, and end up with nearly monochromatic light. That leaves about 1/10000 of the original light power.  Now, to obtain spatial coherence (which allows a laser to be focused to a small spot), you would need to put a tiny pinhole (a micron or two wide) at the focus of the filtered sunlight.  Try focusing sunlight and you'll find that it is difficult to get a spot smaller than about a millimeter. So the pinhole throws away at least 99.999 % of the monochromatic light.  Now you've got only 1/10,000,000,000 of the light you started with -- and it's still not as coherent as a laser.

On the other hand, if the objective is simply to get highly monochromatic light for experiments such as testing spectral response of photosynthesis or light sensors, all you would need is a prism or diffraction grating, a slit filter, and a lens.

Answer (score 3):

Even with perfect filtering (answer of S. McGrew), one can still distinguish filtered sunlight from true laser light by using the [2nd-order autocorrelation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_coherence) $g^2(τ)$.

For a laser: $g^2(0) = 1$.

For thermal light (e.g. sunlight): $g^2(0) = 2$

In words: While the temporal arrival time of laser photons is randomly distributed (poissonian distribution), thermal photons arrive in small bunches (Bose-Einstein distribution). This can be measured with a [Hanbury-Brown-Twiss experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect).